# Compare entries to bucketed table thresholds, as they get populated in an SQL database

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to compare live sensor data stored in an SQL database to a table of "acceptable thresholds".

Each entry in the database has three variables that identify it, and then a series of independent variables which I'm trying to compare.

This is the table to which I'd like to compare each entry. 'Gear', 'Throttle Bucket' and '% Load' are the three variables that I want to use to identify which row from the comparison table I want to compare each entry to.

```
Gear    Throttle Bucket % Load  Sensor 1 Expected   Sensor 2 Expected   Sensor 3 Expected
 1          1000-1500    0-50         40.1                 72.4                 8.7
 1          1000-1500    51-100       58.8                 70.4                 17.5
 1          1000-1500    0-50         79.0                 68.5                 22.5
 1          1000-1500    51-100       40.2                 71.7                 8.5
 2          1000-1500    0-50         58.6                 70.6                 16.9
 2          1000-1500    51-100       43.9                 71.0                 10.1
 2          1000-1500    0-50         46.6                 67.4                 14.3
 2          1000-1500    51-100       78.5                 95.4                 25.0
 3          1000-1500    0-50         17.7                 68.4                 3.7
 3          1000-1500    51-100       47.7                 88.4                 19.7
 3          1000-1500    0-50         46.6                 67.4                 14.3
 3          1000-1500    51-100       78.5                 95.4                 25.0
 4          1000-1500    0-50         17.7                 68.4                 3.7
 4          1000-1500    0-50         40.2                 71.7                 8.5
 4          1000-1500    51-100       77.7                 69.2                 23.8
```

And this is how the data is coming into the server.

```
Entry Number    Gear    Throttle    % Load  Sensor 1    Sensor 2    Sensor 3
     1           2        1134        36%     34.1        76.4        9.7
     2           4        1758        87%     47.6        89.4        14.5
     3           3        1642        15%     52.6        64.5        17.3
     4           1        1224        51%     48.6        59.7        4.2
     5           4        1421        34%     61.4        74.9        3.9
     6           2        1801        73%     52.9        88.4        12.5
```

So what I've been trying to do is for every entry of that table, and using the value for "Gear", "Throttle" and '% Load", find out what the expected value for each of the sensors should've been and calculate the percent difference.

I have the "Comparison Table" stored locally as a Pandas dataframe, and every morning I bulk download all the entries from the live sensor data (approximately 1000 lines).

I've put together a loop for iterrows but I'm having trouble comparing float values to the bucketed columns. And I'm also having trouble setting three different conditions to "triangulate" on the correct line.

Please let me know if there is any information that I've missed. I appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: Just to further clarify. For example, for Entry Number 1, Gear would obviously be "2", then the Throttle Bucket would be 1000-1500 and the % Load Bucket would be 0-50%. Then Sensor 1 Expected = 58.6, Sensor 1 Actual = 34.1

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in SQL or pandas? If it's SQL, then you should tag your question with the database that you are using: MySQL, oracle, SQL Server...?

Comment: I'm loking for a Pandas solution, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Not sure how or if it's allowed to bump an unanswered question.